Why did Nandhishwara tear away the pages of Soundharya Lahari when Parwathi Dhevi gave them to Adi Shankara?
As far as I know this is found in Markandheya Samhitha. The story goes that Shankara received 5 sphatika Lingas, Ratnagarbha Ganapathi from Siva and Soundharya Lahari by Parwathi Dhevi. But Nandhishwara tore away the last 59 pages from the Thantram and allowed Shankara to only take away the first 41 shlokas. I am looking for reason of this action of Nandhishwara.
